# Guardar copia de la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, windows

Llamo una funcion php para hacer una copia de la base de datos con el metodo ajax asi:

```
            $.ajax({
                data: processData,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'core/CopyDataBase.php', // fuction
            })
```

la funcion me regresa la variable `$content` la cual contiene la informacion de la base de datos.

Lo que deseo hacer es guardar el contenido de la variable en un archivo `.sql` y que una vez termine el proceso aparezca el cuadro de dialogo "guardar como" con el nombre sugerido que se le envie ej: `basedatos.sql`

```
    .done(function (processResult) {
        // cuadro de dialogo guardar como
    }
```

Es posible hacerlo con jquery? Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo con AJAX tienes que trabajar con `blob`, para ello la llamada AJAX quedaría así:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'native',
  url: "CopyDataBase.php",
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },
  success: function(blob){
      let link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = "backup_" + new Date() + ".sql";
      link.click();
  }
});
```

Desde PHP tienes que devolver el archivo `.sql` en `blob`.

Comment: Lo quiero hacer asi para poder mostrar al usuario un mensaje y un preloader mientras se hace el proceso

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, pero esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta. Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio, si te das cuenta en la parte de abajo dice "añade un comentario", eso hice!